# Probability distributions for Grothendieck topologies

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, pr.probability

The motivation for asking this question comes from looking at the works of Bhargava and co-workers on the statistics of certain properties of elliptic curves and other abelian varieties, hyper-elliptic curves, binary quadratic forms etc. Typically they order these objects by height, and then, go on to show that a certain fraction or average of them have a certain property, e.g., satisfy the BSD conjecture.

I wondered if in doing so they were implicitly defining probability distributions on the corresponding moduli spaces of these objects, and if so, how to make the definition rigorous. Since the question of measures and distributions in the algebraic-geometric context seemed to be of intrinsic interest, I looked for literature on measures and distributions on algebraic varieties/schemes/stacks, but did not find any (except for motivic measures which did not seem relevant.)

In particular I had wondered if the concept of Borel $\sigma$-algebra had been adapted to Grothendieck topologies and used to define distributions in etale topology and other topoi of arithmetic interest.

I had asked a brief and broad question earlier in the hope of getting some pointers to the literature, but it seems I should have asked a motivated and more focused question instead. Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) defines a probability distribution, because finite sets would have probability zero ("are 0% of the total") and then countable additivity means the total probability would also be zero.

Comment: But other than that, the question about Grothendieck topologies is a good one. However, for a site that isn't a poset, how would one deal with the different maps? A $\sigma$-algebra works because it is a kind of lattice. One could abstract the lattice properties that make sense for categories or even sites, but then defining a measure would have to be quite different to what we are used to.